# Help with factorials, permutations, and combinations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I am an eighth grader in need of some help.  I was assigned a school project on making a java application that computes the total permutations of to given numbers where nPr and later on nCr.  I understand the equation for permutations is n! divided by (r-1)!, but what is the equation for combinations by the terms of n and r?

Comment: $n!\over (n-r)! r!$. For permutations you divide by $(n-r)!$, not $(r-1)!$.

Comment: You could just look it up in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula). $\displaystyle n\mathrm{C}r =\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

Comment: Alright, thank you guys so much!

Comment: @CodeAdmiral: Note: your formula for $n\mathrm{P}r$ is **incorrect**: it should be $n!$ divided by $(n-r)!$, not divided by $(r-1)!$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to *derive* the formula from the number of permutations, $n\mathrm{P}r$, is the following:

To count the number of permutations of $r$ elements out of $n$, you can first select the $r$ elements, which can be done in $n\mathrm{C}r$ ways; and then you can order them, which can be done in $r\mathrm{P}r$ ways (you are now only ordering the $r$ elements you chose). That is,
$$n\mathrm{P}r = n\mathrm{C}r\times r\mathrm{P}r.$$
Since you already know that $n\mathrm{P}r = n!/(n-r)!$ and that $r\mathrm{P}r = r!$, then solving for $n\mathrm{C}r$ we get:
$$n\mathrm{C}r = \frac{n\mathrm{P}r}{r\mathrm{P}r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete writing a formal answer (as it has been answered in the comments):

$\displaystyle n\mathrm{P}r =\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$

and

$\displaystyle n\mathrm{C}r =\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$